# Is there an Open XML parser for C++?

Tags: c++, powerpoint, openxml

I want to scan a PowerPoint 2007 file, but I'm trying to do it with C++. Is there any Open XML parser for C++?

Comment: Straight up C++ or C++/CLI?  Because if it's the latter, you can just use the managed OpenXML SDK (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6E744E5-36E9-45F5-8D8C-331DF206E0D0&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a newly released C library called libOPC which has the same intent as the Open XML SDK, but can be used in all of Linux/Windows/Mac/etc. You can read about it here: [libOPC version 0.0.1 released](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dmahugh/archive/2011/04/19/libopc-version-0-0-1-released.aspx) and get the [code from CodePlex](http://libopc.codeplex.com/) (be sure to check the [documentation page](http://libopc.codeplex.com/documentation) for demo videos).

Answer (score 0):

Not yet. But you can make one. The standards specification files are pretty clear, aren't they ;)

Alternatively you can convert http://phppowerpoint.codeplex.com/ using http://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is try c++ binding directly.  (more useful when you want to check specific small part of document)

http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/IDL_Files_and_Cpp#Concrete_Example

Answer (score -3):

There are several.

Xerces is the most comprehensive:  http://xerces.apache.org/
TinyXML is popular: http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/
Expat is my favorite: http://expat.sourceforge.net/

You can find more information on Google : [XML parser C++](http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=XML%20parser%20C%2b%2b)

Comment: You misread my question.. I'm looking for OpenXML, the Office 2007 format, not just ANY XML parser.

Comment: One would assume that OpenXML is simply just XML document. If you had said I wanted to convert an Office 2007 document into 'X' then you made hade a ligit question.

Comment: The thing is, I'm a bit pressed for time and would rather not read the specs and adapt them to a generic tool. I was hoping there was something a la the OpenXML SDK for CLR that I could use.

Thanks anyway though!

Comment: Treating OOXML as a plain XML format and trying to parse it from scratch could keep you busy for the next decade or so. Probably not the best way to go. ;)